# Cannot convert CustomPageWebLinks from source to metadata

Tags: salesforcedx

It does not seem possible to convert objects of type `CustomPageWebLink` from source to metadata. These objects are stored in `main/default/weblinks`. I can push the weblinks to a new scratch org and they are created correctly, I can pull new weblinks created in a scratch org to my local source and everything seems to be correct. But I cannot convert these to metadata api, the command:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi-converted-source -n 'package name'
```

fails with the error:

```
ERROR running force:source:convert:  Component conversion failed: /home/marco/workspace/grooveApex/mdapi-converted-source/Groove/emailservices/test.custompageweblink: Could not infer a metadata type
```

To reproduce, simply:

1. create a scratch org
2. From setup, select "Custom Links" and create a new one
3. Pull the newly created object locally: `sfdx force:source:pull -u scratchOrg`
4. Try to convert, you will get the error

I was not able to find any information around this error, other than [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2841#issuecomment-846293781) but I do want to convert these weblinks! Furthermore, if I ignore them in `.forceignore` then I cannot even push them to a brand new scratch org and I need those links for my package to work.

Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok nevermind I did actually find [a related issue in the SFDX cli GitHub repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1143), it was posted 16 days ago.

tl; dr; this is fixed in sfdx cli version 7.115.0

Comment: I guess it should be 7.115.0 and not 1.115.0. I did a  correction so it helps others